# WPF ComboBox displaying Object Type after styling

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

In my project I am using a ComboBox with my custom objects like Employees and using DisplayMemberPath="Description".
This all works perfectly as expected.

Because this application is targeted to be used with a touchscreen, I had to style the scrollbar and make it wider which meant that I had to create a new template for the ScrolViewer. This also turned out quite nicely.

The problem comes in when I had to create a new ControlTemplate for the ComboBox which I need so that I can add the ScrollViewerControlTemplate to the ScrollViewer of the ComboBox. I used Blend to generate the ControlTemplate for me and then Bound the ScrollViewerControlTemplate to the ScrollViewer within the ComboBox ControlTemplate.

Excelent, only problem is that the ComboBox displays the correct text within the dropdown part of the control but the ToggleButton part of the control displays the Object Type which is [NameSpace].Employee.

I tried changing the ContentPresenter but without to much success.

```
<ContentPresenter 
                    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" 
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didnt have time to figure out exactly what the problem was but what I did to fix the problem was to create a new window, drag one ComboBox onto the page and generated the Xaml again and copied all of it into the App.Xaml file.

I think I was missing some styles which is what caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ComboBox` template, the content of that area should be bound to the `SelectionBoxItem` properties.  So, if you are using a `ContentPresenter` to display the selection:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectionBoxItem" />
```

If you are using a `ToggleButton`'s content area, you would do something like so:

```
<ToggleButton Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
              ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" />
```

Comment: Hey fella, sorry I cant mark this as the answer for you as I had already changed and fixed the problem and cannot test your suggestion.